# Prevent users from disabling an extension in the incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Users in a company that I work for have access to disable company managed extensions when they are in incognito mode.

For eg: a user can disable the DLP solutions through incognito browser

Are there any ways to enforce the extensions to remain enabled in incognito mode and prevent users from disabling the option?

PS - posted it already on the chrome community platform. No response

Comment: Use force-installed extensions via policies.

Comment: The force-installed extensions does not work in incognito mode